# VHDL: Cosine Lookup Table

Tags: drawing, vhdl, fpga, lookup-tables, vga

I am working with VGA on my Basys3 FPGA, and I currently want to draw a zone plate, for which the equation is (1 + cos(k*r^2)) / 2, where r is the distance from the plate center, and k=2*pi/lambda is the wavenumber, which determines the scale of the plate. I am guessing the best course of action would be to use a cosine LUT, but I really have no idea how to create one. I somewhat understand the idea behind it, but I don't know how to write one and what values it should contain.

This is the code I am trying to test out:

The only problem with this now is that I do not know what values to fill the `memory_type :=()` with, so that it will equal the k*r^2 from the formula.

```
architecture Behavioral of VGAdraw is

signal i : integer range 0 to 29:=0;
signal r : integer :=2;
type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer range -128 to 127; 
signal cosine : memory_type :=();

begin

process(CLK)
begin
if (CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1') then
    if (cntHor >= 0) AND (cntHor <= cstHorAL - 1) then
            RED <= conv_std_logic_vector ((1 - cosine (i)) / 2, 8) (7 downto 4);
            GREEN <= conv_std_logic_vector ((1 - cosine (i)) / 2, 8) (7 downto 4);
            BLUE <= conv_std_logic_vector ((1 - cosine (i)) / 2, 8) (7 downto 4);
            i <= i + 1;
    else
            RED <= "0000";
            GREEN <= "0000";
            BLUE <= "0000";
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

cntHor - horizontal counter

cstHorAL - nr of pixels on an active line

I cannot post the image itself due to lack of reputation, but this is what it should look like: http://handforgedvideo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/1920x1080p24_Luma_Zone_Plate_Main.png

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: A LUT can be made as a ROM that is initialized with the function values, or simply as a function that is then converted to combinatorial logic by the synthesis tool.  Please include the code part that shows argument and result format and precision for a more better answer.

Comment: The thing is, I don't even know how to get started. The code I have added is what I found someplace else, and I am trying to test it out. But I really don't know how it works, what are those values in the case structure and how to connect this to my color outputs to draw the zone plate using the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your general code isn't too far off, but as Morten pointed out, you don't specify the format of the input (theta) or the outputs (sin_data and cos_data).  Are they fixed point values?  Where's the fractional point?  Are they just integers?

You say:

> I am guessing the best course of action would be to use a cosine LUT, but I really have no idea how to create one.

I presume you mean by "LUT" a generic "lookup table".  The use of "LUT" is ambiguous in your question since you also mention the Basys3.  In FPGA literature, LUT is a specific type of logic structure on an FPGA.  It also means "lookup table", but the size and complexity are limited to a few digital inputs.  There are no "cosine LUT" objects available.  I just wanted to be clear that by "LUT" you mean a generic lookup table.

Now, your code isn't too far off.  It is indeed a lookup table to pass in `theta` and output `sin_data` and `cos_data`.  The questions are a) whether or not your outputs accurately represent the function and b) whether or not your implementation is the most efficient.

For the former, I'm not sure since you don't specify the input and output format.  Also, you don't specify the mapping between ϴ and your function.  Is ϴ the argument to cos()?  Or is it k?  Or is it λ?

For the latter, take a look at Xilinx [UG901](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2016_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf).  It gives examples of how to infer ROMs (see the 'ROM HDL Coding Techniques' section).  Your code, as written, would probably be the least efficient method.  You need two lookup tables with 4K entries each (`sin_data` and `cos_data`), so two 4K x 12bit.  You'd be better off with a ROM build from a block RAM.

Comment: That is the problem with borrowed code.. I don't fully understand it. Anyway, I tried to implement this using a more simple code. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @LeventeRigán Do you intend the code to by synthesizable?

Comment: Yes, eventually, that would be the goal :)

Comment: If your goal is synthesizable code, you can't use cos() as you have it written.  You synthesize a signal based upon a function such as this.  You can, however, derive constants from cos().  I recommend you look through UG901 for the style to synthesize a ROM, then initialize the ROM contents (the initial value is a constant value) with a call to cos().

Comment: Ok, I checked it out, and it seems my previous code was a bit closer to how the `process(CLK)` should look like. But then I still don't know how to get to the drawing part. I assign the constants that I derive from the cos() to the color outputs?

Comment: @LeventeRigán I'm not a VGA expert, so I'm not sure how to generate the VGA output.  But I can speak to your generation of cos() and sin() outputs based upon some input.  I get that you want to compute `1 + cos(k*r^2)`.  Is `k` the input?  Is `r` a constant?  It still isn't clear what your inputs and outputs are or how they are formatted.  Are they integers?  Fixed point?  Give more detail on the inputs and outputs and I can provide more assistance.